# In production mode, react helmet async is not working and How react helmet async works?

Tags: reactjs, django, seo, react-helmet

Recently, I started playing with meta tags in react. After some research, I found that react-helmet-async is the best library to set meta tags for each page. however, I wanted to want set meta tags for few pages conditionally.

I setup metatags for two pages differently, take a look...

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HelmetProvider>
      <App/>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

pageOne.jsx

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/getTrack/',{params: {id: this.props.match.params.id}})
    .then((res) => this.setState({trackData: res.data, isLoading: false}))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
render() {
        return (
            this.state.isLoading?
                <div className="page-loader">
                    <Helmet>
                        {/* Page sittings */}
                        <meta charset="utf-8" />
                        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                        
                        {/* Primary Meta Tags */}
                        <title>Loading...</title>
                    </Helmet>
                </div>
            :
            <div className="main-page">
                <Helmet>
                    {/* Page sittings */}
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                    
                    {/* Primary Meta Tags */}
                    <title>{this.state.trackData.title}</title>
                    <meta name="title" content={this.state.trackData.title}/>
                    <meta name="description" content={this.state.trackData.desc}/>
                    
                    {/* Open Graph / Facebook */}
                    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
                    <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/"/>
                    <meta property="og:title" content={this.state.trackData.title}/>
                    <meta property="og:description" content={this.state.trackData.desc}/>
                    <meta property="og:image" content="/logo192.png"/>
                    
                    {/* Twitter */}
                    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
                    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://example.com/"/>
                    <meta property="twitter:title" content={this.state.trackData.title}/>
                    <meta property="twitter:description" content={this.state.trackData.desc}/>
                    <meta property="twitter:image" content="/logo192.png"/>
                </Helmet>
            </div>
         )
    }
```

pageTwo.jsx

```
                <Helmet>
                    {/* Primary Meta Tags */}
                    <title>XYZ</title>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <meta name="title" content="xyz"/>
                    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                    <meta name="description" content="xyz"/>
                    {/* Open Graph / Facebook */}
                    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
                    <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/"/>
                    <meta property="og:title" content="xyz"/>
                    <meta property="og:description" content="xyz"/>
                    <meta property="og:image" content="/logo192.png"/>
                    {/* Twitter */}
                    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
                    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://example.com/"/>
                    <meta property="twitter:title" content="xzy"/>
                    <meta property="twitter:description" content="xzy"/>
                    <meta property="twitter:image" content="/logo192.png"/>
                </Helmet>
```

> "react": "^17.0.1"
> "react-helmet-async": "^1.0.9",

I'm using django for backend

It is working in development mode but not in production mode. my web app doesn't have any metatags, I don't understand, how react-helmet-async is working?

Is this kind of metatags are shareable?

what is the alternative solution for such kind of work?

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?

Comment: Yes, if you want to build a website that is either marketplace or community, then react is a bad option for you because you need good SEO, and you can archive good SEO if you are rending the page on the server-side, not client-side. I finally switched to NEXTJS because it developed to tackle these issues.

Comment: Thats not exactly a solution for this problem...

Comment: Now, react provide server-side rending so you can change meta tags dynamically.

Comment: @SatyamskillzIN where does react provide server side rending? do you have any docs ?

Comment: Read this docs, https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/37